# Problem restoring partial mariabackup

Tags: backup, ubuntu, tablespaces, mariadb-10.3

I follow this [method](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/partial-backup-and-restore-with-mariabackup/) to perform a partial and incremental backup of my database on two servers, bskpserver and devserver. Everything works fine except for some tables. When I try to restore them on devserver, I get an error that says:

```
ALTER TABLE `database`.`tables` IMPORT TABLESPACE;
ERROR 1808 (HY000): Schema mismatch (Column last_change precise type mismatch, it's 0X80607 in the table and 0X607 in the tablespace meta file)
```

After looking into it, I found out it's a bug. This happens when the tables were created in an older version. Even after recreating the table and trying the backup again, the issue persists. All the servers are running on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS and MariaDB 10.3.38.